# 'No matching function' -error when trying to insert to a set (c++)

Tags: c++, set, overloading, operator-keyword

I have the following code:

```
class asd {  
    public:  
    int b;  
    asd() { b = rand() % 10; }  
    bool operator<(asd &other) { return b < other.b; }  
};

int main() {  
    asd * c; c = new asd();  
    set <asd> uaua;  
    uaua.insert(c);  
}
```

Yet when running it, I get this error:

`main.cpp|36|error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<asd, std::less<asd>, std::allocator<asd> >::insert(asd*&)’|`

I'm using g++ 4.4.3

Could someone please tell me where I'm going wrong? I've tried to crack this for a good while, but can't seem to find the solution. Thanks

Comment: Unrelated to the question: you should implement `operator<` as a free function if possible, and if implemented as a method (this rule is valid for all other methods) it should be constant as it does not modify the object to which it is applied.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a set of `asd`, and you're trying to add a pointer.

Use:

```
asd c; 
set <asd> uaua;
uaua.insert(c);
```

Comment: +1, you can also use construction in place: `set<asd> uaua; uaua.insert( asd() );`

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring `set<asd*>` instead of just `set<asd>`.